# how to make the square into arc borders?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, shapes

[image]

I want to make this kind of arc square border in android. The idea is to set border of the image and only inside picture will show up like the mask. outer picture will be cropped or won't be displayed

I have tried many ways but not able to solve this issue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you could post what you've tried so far specifically. Maybe someone can then recognise what you were doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw that piece by piece using `drawLine()` and `drawArc()` functions from the Canvas.
You can check how to use this [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawArc(android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. You can achieve it by [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawArc(android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint)).

   Please go through to draw the shape you want
2. You can use the library [android-shape-imageview](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview)

   ```
    <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.mask.PorterShapeImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:siShape="@drawable/shape_bg"
       android:src="@drawable/face"
       app:siSquare="true"/>
   ```

Output on using Library looks like

[image]

You can get different shapes by replacing **siShape** in **ImageView**

[image]